# Run a side effect after slice (redux state) update completed

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit and I would like to store the latest state of a slice in sessionStorage. I know that I can use store.subscribe() to handle whole state updates but what I am after is to catch a specific slice update.

I am able to achieve it by using a selector to slice in a custom hook. Please see the code below.

Is there a property/functionality in createSlice to hook on to state updates to run a side effect after the state update completes, similar to prepare attribute.

```js
//slice
export const aliasSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'alias',
    initialState: initState ,
    reducers: {
        setAlias: (state, action) => action.payload
    },
})

export const { setAlias } = aliasSlice.actions

export const selectAlias = state => state.alias
```

```js
//custom hook
const useSessionStrorage = () => {
    const alias = useSelector(selectAlias)

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(alias)
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('mySessionStorageKey', alias)
    },[alias])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing in RTK.

Generally I'd recommend you to not handle that on component level, but either in a `subscribe`, a custom middleware or - probably the easiest way - by using `redux-persist` which is made for that purpose and very configurable.

In a middleware, it would look like this:

```js
const myMw = api => next => action => {
  const lastValue = mySelector(api.getState)
  const result = next(action)
  const newValue = mySelector(api.getState)
  if (lastValue !== newValue) {
    // do something
  }
  return result
}
```

with `subscribe`:

```js
let lastValue = mySelector(store.getState)
store.subscribe(() => {
  const newvalue = mySelector(store.getState)
  if (lastValue !== newValue) {
    // do something
  }
  lastValue = newValue
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to catch an update for a specific slice using subscribe(), if not how can I make sure that It is the specific slice that has been updated. On the other hand Middleware runs before the state update so I can not make sure that state is updated. Thank you for your answer and all the hard work you have done for open source.

Comment: Middleware runs "around" the reducer. I'll add a little example above.